# how to validate payment was made

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I have read about paypal IPN but that has delays in notification.

I watched this video on setting up a paypal subscription button

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jHC9BoRDEOY

but the thing I am missing is that I add a url that paypal will go to after payment.  When this url is hit, I need to immediately verify that payment was made(ie. I want it so if a user goes to that url without paying, we don't accidentally continue the process since he has not paid yet).

so, how can I 
    1. have paypal feed me some kind of unique id when it brings up my url
    2. call back to paypal to verify that payment as been made.

Lastly, how can I test this all out on the paypal sandbox to make sure everything is working together?

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 0):

I did find this but this is not using the buttons at all.  Is there not a way to use the buttons?

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-recurringPaymentProfile-curl-etc/

thanks,
Dean

Comment: This link is for [PayPal Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/), but the video mentioned in the question is talking about [PayPal Standards](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/wp_standard_overview/)

Comment: I am not sure I care about which product and just wanted to solve my issue with any product and finally did.